# we need to write a query to find out the number of employee in a Dept. and also total employee in an orginzation

Tags: sql

We have an Employee Table with following data

```
EMID   Emp      DptName
1     Rahul     HR
2     Raj       HR
3     Rajat    Account
4    Abhishek   Account
5    Nakul     Admin
6    Arjun     Admin
7    Bhim      Admin
```

We need a below output

```
DptName                 no of emp    Total emp
-------------------- ----------   ---------
HR                            2      7
Account                       2      7
Admin                         3      7
```

How can we do this?

please let me know how can we update the below query to achieve the above output.

```
select DptName, count(*) "no of emp" 
from employee group by DptName
```

Comment: "We" should figure out what database "we" are using and appropriately tag the question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select DptName, count(*) as num_in_dept, sum(count(*)) over () as total
from employee
group by DptName
```

Comment: select DptName, count(*) as num_in_dept, sum(count(*)) as total
from employee
group by DptName